# NSTextView not responding in an app without dock icon

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstextview

I have a menulet app with an NSTextView in it. I don't want the app to appear in the dock, so I wrote

```
<key>LSUIElement</key>
<true/>
```

in the Info.plist file.

But if this option is enabled, somehow an NSTextView in the menu stops responding at all.

How can I make it respond again? Maybe there are any other ways to hide the dock icon?

Thank you!

IMPORTANT UPDATE: This bug has been spotted only on Mac OS 10.6 and higher

Answer (score 0):

The documentation states that keyboard events are not supported in views that are attached to a menu item (see [Application Menu and Pop-up List Programming Topics](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MenuList/Articles/ViewsInMenuItems.html)).

That said, I had no problem creating a minimal sample app without Dock icon and a text view embedded in a status item's menu, so your problem is likely somewhere else. You can download my sample app [here](http://omz-software.com/temp/TextViewMenu.zip).

Comment: Do you have Mac OS 10.5.X? Take it or leave it but on Mac OS 10.6.6 your sample app doesn't work...

Comment: When I click at the UITextView and try to input text it just doesn't work

Comment: No idea, works fine here, except for the text view's context menu and shortcuts that involve the command key (so copy/paste doesn't work), but entering text is no problem.

Comment: That's really weird... I'll try to find another 10.6.6 Mac and test it there, then